# Crystal Reports - Underlay section overlays lines (drawing object)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I have a problem with CR (version that ships with VS2008). Report has two report headers, one of them is used for watermark (a picture), using the "Underlay following sections" option.

The problem is that, while this picture underlays field objects, it overlays lines in all of the sections (details, report footer etc...).

Any solutions? Help would be mostly appreciated, I'm starting to lose my hair ...

Comment: Is it possible to put some picture what the output look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found "a solution" by replacing the line object with a textbox object, whose one of the borders is set to single. This way, the watermark stays under, and I have my line.

This might be a bug in CR ...

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar challenge, I had an image in Header 'A' which was set to underlay following sections. The challenge was when I built a Header 'B' and drew a box or a line, they were obscured by the image.

(Text boxes worked fine but I needed to draw a box and some lines.)

The work around was I simply put a Sub report into Header 'B' and then I went into the sub report, drew all my boxes and lines and great news, they all appeared as I hoped when I ran the report. I hope this helps somebody else.

R.